# Test class for a controller - Unable to set the variable in the constructor

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, null-pointer

I have a controller:

```
public class XYZcontroller{
    public object__c sr{get;set;}
    public String srid;
    public XYZcontroller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        sr = (object__c) controller.getRecord();
        srid = String.valueOf(sr.Id).substring(0, 15);
        String pageMessage = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('pageMessage');
        boolean doNotDisplay;
        String referrer = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('REFERER');
        if(referrer.contains(srid+ '/e')){
            doNotDisplay=false;
        }else{
            doNotDisplay=true;
        }
    }
}
```

Test class for the above:

```
@isTest
public class xyzControllerTest{        
    static testMethod void testMethod1(){        
        object__c sr = new object__c (Name='test');
        insert sr;
        PageReference pageRef = Page.Thepage;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('pageMessage', 'Amessage');     
        ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('REFERER', sr.id + '/e');
        ApexPages.StandardController stdcontroller = new ApexPages.StandardController(sr);

        xyzController controller = new xyzController(stdcontroller);     
    }    
}
```

In the above test class I get an error at line - `xyzController controller = new xyzController(stdcontroller);`  saying:

Error Message:

> System.NullPointerException: Argument 1 cannot be null Stack Trace External entry point Class.xyzControllerTest.testMethod1: line 14, column 1

I am thinking it is due to the `public String srid;` in the `XYZcontroller` which does not get a value inside the constructor. ( `srid = String.valueOf(sr.Id).substring(0, 15);` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not passing `REFERER` as parameter which you are trying to access in the constructor, that's why the error is.

So, before creating instance of the stdController, assign header value.

```
@isTest
public class xyzControllerTest{


 static testMethod void testMethod1(){

     object__c sr = new object__c (Name='test');
     insert sr;
     PageReference pageRef = Page.Thepage;
     Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
     ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',sr.Id);
     ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('pageMessage', 'Amessage');  
     ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('REFERER', sr.id + '/e');  
     ApexPages.StandardController stdcontroller = new ApexPages.StandardController(sr);

     xyzController controller = new xyzController(stdcontroller);     
 }

}
```

**Controller**

Also, put a null check before using `referrer`

```
public class XYZcontroller{
public object__c sr{get;set;}
public String srid {get;set;}
public XYZcontroller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
{
    sr = (object__c) controller.getRecord();
    srid = String.valueOf(controller.getId()).substring(0, 15);
    String pageMessage = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('pageMessage');
    boolean doNotDisplay;

    String referrer = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('REFERER');
    if(referrer !=null && referrer.contains(srid+ '/e'))
    {
        doNotDisplay = false;
    }else
    {
        doNotDisplay=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: He is using standard controller  so its not required

Comment: I got it, issue in the referrer

Comment: I do have the referrer before `ApexPages.StandardController` but still the same error comes up

Comment: can you use my code and check if it works

Comment: Santanu , I still get the same error with your code as well. Is this because `public String srid;` is not set in the constructor?

Comment: can you use public String srid {get;set;}

Comment: I can , but the variables is not used in VF page. Although I tried using get;set; but even then I get the same error. Weird! What am I missing!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60740/discussion-between-santanu-boral-and-sfdcbat).

Answer (score 1):

Below code is running with 90% coverage. Please note the changes.

```
@isTest
    public class xyzControllerTest{


     static testMethod void testMethod1(){

         object__c sr = new object__c (Name='test');
         insert sr;
         ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('pageMessage', 'Amessage');         
         ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('REFERER', sr.id + '/e');
         ApexPages.StandardController stdcontroller = new ApexPages.StandardController(sr);
         xyzController controller = new xyzController(stdcontroller);     
     }

    }
```

Comment: This does give the error. I removed - `Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);` only rest of the code I think is the same as what I have in the question. Correct?

Comment: Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef) and ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put both not required at same time

Comment: Ok! I removed them and ran the test again . It give me the same error message. Why does it says - `System.NullPointerException: Argument 1 cannot be null` where I create a new object of the controller? Any idea?

Comment: What are the other fields in your Object. I just created Object__c without any custom field and it worked without any issue

Comment: Only required field is Name, no need of custom field to create the record

Comment: did you copy paste the exact code I wrote above?  see this https://youtu.be/tvIU_A2EOJU

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60760/discussion-between-avijit-chakraborty-and-sfdcbat).